# Equation of surface

Tags: surfaces, parametric

Suppose we have a surface f(x, y) =4, 0<x<4, 0<y<4. If we start rotating the surface with constant angular velocity in the z axis by 180 degrees what will be the equation of each plane after t=0 such that the point 2,2,4 will be a point of every plane?

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. You might want to look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), particularly for how to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Your question is simply a problem statement without any context such as what you have tried, or what you got stuck on, or some kind of detailed mathematical question regarding your unsuccessful attempts. Questions without such context can attract down votes and close votes on this site.

Comment: Please also typeset your mathematical formulas using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).